# Is it possible to replicate the ENIAC using logic gates

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture, computers, programmable-logic

Can one rebuild a small scaled model of the original ENIAC computer using only logic gates?

Comment: Of course, how could it be otherwise?

Comment: Why you want to do it?

Comment: For inspiration, have a look at http://www.megaprocessor.com/.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ENIAC used logic gates, they were just made up of vacuum tubes.  The ENIAC had thousands of them. 6,550 out of the 18,800 tubes in the computer (circa 1946) were dual-triode 6SN7GTs. Each tube was used as a flip-flop and represented one bit, one side the 1, and the other side the 0.

The ENIAC used ten-position [ring counters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_counter) to store digits in ten's complement representation. Each digit used 28 vacuum tubes, 10 of which were the dual triodes making up the flip-flops of the ring counter (the ten tubes shown on the right in the picture below).

[image]

Arithmetic was performed by counting pulses with the ring counters and generating a carry if the counter wrapped around. ENIAC had twenty ten-digit signed accumulators.

[image]

So you could start out by building one of the accumulators.  You could cheat and just use a ring-counter IC, such as a [CD4017](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4017b.pdf); but to be more faithful, you should build one out of ten flip-flops plus additional logic as needed. To really capture the original design, you could build one out of transistors.

Constants were entered using punched cards; programming was done using a combination of rotary switches and jumper cables.

[image]

[This document](http://ftp.arl.mil/mike/comphist/46eniac-report/chap1.html) has a pretty good description of how it worked, including timing diagram as shown below.  Note a '1' was represented by -290v, and a '0' by -345v.

[image]

[This article](http://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/Knuth_Don_X4100/PDF_index/k-8-pdf/k-8-r5367-1-ENIAC-circuits.pdf) contains many of the electronic circuits used in the ENIAC, and here is the [user's manual](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/univOfPennsylvania/eniac/ENIAC_Operating_Manual_Jun46.pdf).

Comment: Interesting - the ring counter approach makes the design more similar to the hand-cranked mechanical desktop calculators of the time than modern Boolean twos-complement systems.

Comment: @pjc50 Other notable decimal computers were the Harvard Mark 1, the IBM 650 and successors 7070 series, and the UNIVAC Solid State (competitor to the 650).

Comment: @tcrosley : and the Harwell computer, which used dekatrons, a single tube that could count to 10.

Comment: Thank you very much i have learnt a little about logic gates iun the past and used a circuit simulator to design an 8 bit add, sub tractor, divider and a compare tor i think i might cheat to start off with and use premade adder, sub tractors and compare tors considering im only 15 :p. i will then move on to doing it a little more properly

Answer (score 1):

That depends on which aspects you want to preserve in your small scale model

- physical appearance? that will be difficult using logic gates :)
- computaional model? of course, you can build a computer with just gates, and you can simulate the eniac on on that computer.
- timing aspects? that will be very difficult, I doubt there is even enough documentation to determine the exact circuits used.

Answer (score 1):

So how "small scale" are you talking about? If you only need code compatibility I think a single, medium-range FPGA chip can hold it all. So we are talking two to four chips here (FPGA, its configuration memory if required and a DRAM chip replacing the magnetic core, maybe an interfacing CPLD.) You can add in another microcontroller to feed the ENIAC-on-FPGA its program and input from and write its output to a microSD card, keypad and/or LCD screen.

If properly designed you can get a hand-held version of ENIAC consists of 8 to 9 chips, a LCD-and-keypad user interface and a battery life of a few hours or days on a single charge of a few 18650 cells.

Comment: That's insane. If you only need code compatibility as you say, you can implement the ENIAC in a small 6-pin microcontroller. DRAM to emulate a 100 _word_ core memory? And the FPGA isn't enough, you need a CPLD in there?

Comment: @pipe Using that MCU you are **emulating** the ENIAC, not **implementing** it. The CPLD is just there to assist some types of FPGA that cannot load its configuration memory on its own, as it is required on some but not all FPGA out there. I know that there are even some FPGA that is Flash-based and need no external configuration memory too but the CPLD is for the FPGAs on the other end of the spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

Not only can one do that, but they did back in the mid 1990s to celebrate the 50th anniversary of the ENIAC. They made the "ENIAC-on-a-chip" using 0.5 micrometer CMOS. The chip measures 7.44 x 5.29 mm.

[https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~jan/eniacproj.html](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ejan/eniacproj.html)

Though I am not sure if that counts as what you would call a "scaled model." I'm guessing you might have something more like a diorama-miniature in mind. In that case, perhaps another anniversary celebrational device is waiting to be made!

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you are asking, but the project here includes a functional ENIAC reproduction and a 1/10 scale model of it: https://hackaday.com/2021/10/19/vcf-east-roars-back-to-life/